# How to remove the most recent when using in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The following gives me a complete list of the records in question:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, STATE, VDATE, COMPLETE_DATE 
from db 
where NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME from db where COMPLETE_DATE != '') 
ORDER BY NAME, STATE, VDATE DESC;
```

Unfortunately, I am interested in all of the records that are not the most recent (according to VDATE) for every name, state. Basically, the exact same result MINUS the record for each name/state combination that contains the most recent VDATE. For every name, state combination, there might be 10 records, each with a VDATE that is the same or different.

How can I eliminate the most recent VDATE from this dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the max vdate for each name,state and use a `not in` thereafter.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, STATE, VDATE, COMPLETE_DATE 
from db 
where (NAME,STATE,VDATE) NOT IN (SELECT NAME,STATE,MAX(VDATE) as MAXVDT
                                 from db 
                                 where COMPLETE_DATE != '' 
                                 GROUP BY NAME,STATE) 
ORDER BY NAME, STATE, VDATE DESC
```

or use a `join` with a derived table containing the max date for each name and state.

```
select d1.ID, d1.NAME, d1.STATE, d1.VDATE, d1.COMPLETE_DATE 
from db d1
join (SELECT NAME,STATE,MAX(VDATE) as MAXVDT
      from db 
      where COMPLETE_DATE != '' 
      GROUP BY NAME,STATE) d2
on d1.name = d2.name and d1.state = d2.state 
where d1.vdate <> d2.maxvdt
order by d1.NAME, d1.STATE, d1.VDATE desc
```

Note that if there is only one vdate per name,state combination both the queries won't return those name,state combination in the result, as that date would be the `max` vdate for that combination.